# Visual Studio - select browser for performance analysis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing an MVC site and I would like to run some performance profiling. So far I've managed to run a few tests but the problem is that there are certain parts of javascript code that are only compatible with the latest browser (this I cannot change) and the profiler uses Internet Explorer for profiling. I haven't been able to test the parts of my site with the newer js code because IE doesn't recognize a lot of the functions I'm using.

Is there a way I can specify the browser used for profiling?

I've tried the following:

- Set chrome as default browser for all possible actions
- Disable internet explorer from OS
- Run profiler and then use the site on chrome

My environment: Windows server 2012 with visual studio 2015

Comment: I'm not sure if visual studio supports performance profiling with other browsers. However if you want to just profile your javascript you can do so though chromes debug tools just hit CTRL+SHIFT+I or F12 and go to the profiling tab.

Comment: @ThomasDevries actually I'm more interested in the methods call time report

Comment: Confirming that this is still an issue.  Regardless of your configured default browser (as described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9650ff2e-3f7f-44b5-8558-916941c4aa25/select-browser-por-performance-analysis?forum=vsdebug), MVS always opens IE for performance profiling.

Comment: Still an issue. Starting a bounty as this is now critical since IE is now forced-closed by Edge meaning that profiling sessions cannot run at all.

Microsoft have identified and closed the issue as low priority.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Performance-Profiler-using-IE/10023125?q=performance+profiler+internet+explorer

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/performance-profiler-uses-Internet-explo/697561?q=performance+profiler+internet+explorer

Comment: Disable extensions in IE to stop redirect to Edge
Internet Explorer uses special a helper object to redirect from IE to Edge. By disabling the third-party extensions feature, you can stop this behaviour.

(1)Open the Run dialog box with the “Windows key + R” shortcut. 
(2)Type “inetcpl.cpl” and click “Ok.” 
(3)Go to the “Advanced” tab. 
(4)Uncheck the “Enable third-party browser extensions” option. 
(5)Click “Apply.” 
(6)Click “Ok” to save changes. 

This doesn't solve the underlying issue, but it does allow the Profiler to keep running and available, to be targeted by any browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

by enabling, you can debug using the selected browsers and enable script debugging also !

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, you may be limited in your options for performance profiling and browser compatibility testing. Here are a few suggestions that may help:

Upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio: Visual Studio 2015 is an older version and may not be compatible with the latest web development technologies. Consider upgrading to a newer version of Visual Studio that supports the latest web technologies and tools.

Visual Studio 2015 by following these steps:

Open your project in Visual Studio 2015.

1. Open the Performance Explorer window by clicking on "Test" -> "Windows" -> "Performance Explorer".
2. Select the profiling session you want to modify and right-click on it.
   , Click on "Properties" to open the "Performance Session Properties" dialog box.
3. In the "General" tab, select "Launch profiling browser" and choose the browser you want to use for profiling from the drop-down list.
   Click "OK" to save your changes.
4. By following these steps, you can switch the profiling browser in Visual Studio 2015 to a browser that supports the JavaScript functions you are using, and then perform performance profiling on your website.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are using the built-in profiling tools in Visual Studio, which are designed to work with Internet Explorer. However, as you have discovered, some of the newer JavaScript features that you are using may not be supported in IE.

To work around this issue, you can try using a different profiling tool that supports modern browsers. One such tool is Google Chrome's built-in DevTools, which includes a powerful JavaScript profiler that can help you identify performance bottlenecks in your code.

To use the Chrome DevTools profiler:

```
1. Open your site in Google Chrome.

2. Press F12 to open the DevTools window.

3. Click on the "Performance" tab.

4. Click on the "Record" button to start profiling.

5. Use your site as you normally would, performing the actions that you want to profile.

6. Click on the "Stop" button to end the profiling session.

7. Analyze the results in the DevTools window to identify performance issues in your code.
```

Note that the Chrome DevTools profiler may produce different results than the Visual Studio profiler, since it is running in a different browser. However, it should still give you valuable insights into the performance of your code.

If you prefer to use the Visual Studio profiler, you may be able to configure it to use a different browser by changing the default browser settings in Visual Studio. To do this:

```
1. Open Visual Studio and go to Tools > Options.

2. In the Options dialog, go to Debugging > General.

3. Under "Web Browser", select the browser that you want to use for profiling.

4. Click "OK" to save your changes.
```

Note that changing the default browser may affect other debugging and testing tasks in Visual Studio, so be sure to test your changes carefully.